# Is it true that every metric subspace of a given metric space is clopen in itself?

Tags: general-topology

Let $E$ be a metric space and let $F$ be a metric subspace of $E$. If $E := \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and if  $F := [0,1] \times \{ 0 \}$, then $F$ is open in $F$, for the open ball $U := B((\frac{1}{2},0); 1)$ with respect to $E$ is such that $F = U \cap F$. But $F$ is also closed in $F$, because the closed ball $V := B((\frac{1}{2},0); 1)$ with respect to $E$ is such that $F = V \cap F$.

Is this just a special case for a metric subspace of a metric space to be clopen in itself? What do I miss?

Comment: $F$ will always be closed and open in $F$ because here there is no meaning to include $E$ here

Comment: So the example is not just a special case, right?

Comment: yes a space is always open and closed in itself;no point taking it as a subspace of another space

Comment: I guess so too. Just not sure if it I am completely right.

Comment: Well, in order to define a topology (or metric) on a subspace, one needs to consider the ambient space. But yes, a subspace is always clopen in itself. Depending on what definition you are working with of the topology, this might require a short proof.

Comment: @LASV As soon as you say the word "topology" it implies that the subspace is both closed and open in itself. It's right there in the definition of topology: "$(X,\tau)$ is a topological space and $\tau$ a topology on $X$ if 1. $X\in \tau$ and $\emptyset\in \tau$, 2. ..."

Comment: I agree with that statement. But depending on how they defined open sets on a subspace, the fact that it is a topology requires a proof, aka one needs to show the empty set and the set itself are open. Ie the set is clopen in itself